# appgallery connect.Upload package. An unknown error occurred. Please try again later

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, appgallery, appgallery-connect, huawei-iap

when I want to upload a new version of my apk after grab my app to upload it go fast to 60% .
and stacks and never continue

screen from console：

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Sometimes it is caused by VPN or proxy of your computer.  Please try
   to disable VPN and proxy, and try again.
2. If you use company’s computer, sometimes some company policy will
   wrongly block some uploading. Normally your computer will popup a message to tell you about it. Pls carefully check if there is any message when
   you are uploading.
3. Normally Huawei AGC will check if the package name of the uploading
   app is used. It will take a while(had better waiting for 2 minutes).
   After the checking, AGC will tell you the result.
4. Try to use different browsers to try(it’s better to clear cache of
   the browser) or reboot your computer.
5. If you still have the issue, please catch video or screenshots, I
   will deeply appreciate it and research it.

Answer (score 0):

You are advised to clear the browser log and upload it again.

If the problem persists, Please provide the error screenshot and browser logs, According to this we can analyze your problem and try to help.